# Angular return promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire, angular-promise

I am new at Javascript and Angular sorry for this question. I am using Anguarfire and trying to get user data from firebase data according to their uid. First gettin auth state and uid and sync to user data.

This should return user info.

```
.factory('Yetki', function($firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth){
    var ref = new Firebase("URL");
     var Yetki = function() { };
              Yetki.Alis = function()  {    

                          $firebaseAuth(ref).$onAuth(function(uyeDurum) {

                          var uyexDurum = uyeDurum;

                          return $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(uyexDurum.uid));
});
}

return Yetki;
})
```

And use role info in that data using here. Angular-permission.

```
.run(function(Yetki, Permission, $q){

    Permission
   .defineRole('fansub', function (stateParams) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      Yetki.Alis().then(function (data) {
        if (data.role === 'fansub') {
          deferred.resolve();
        } else {
          deferred.reject();
        }
      }, function () {
        // Error with request
        deferred.reject();
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    });
```

**Edit-1:**

$loaded():
Returns a promise which is resolved when the initial object data has been downloaded from the database. The promise resolves to the $firebaseObject itself.
As a shortcut, the resolve() / reject() methods can optionally be passed directly into $loaded():

Example:

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.$loaded()
.then(function(data) {
console.log(data === obj); // true
})
.catch(function(error) {
console.error("Error:", error);
});


var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.$loaded(
function(data) {
console.log(data === obj); // true
},
function(error) {
console.error("Error:", error);
}
);
```

My Case:

```
.factory('Yetki', function($firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth){
var ref = new Firebase("https://boiling-torch-7173.firebaseio.com");
return {
Alis: function()  { 
 $firebaseAuth(ref).$onAuth(function(uyeDurum) {
 var uyexDurum = uyeDurum;
 var rek = ref.child('users').child(uyexDurum.uid);
 var obj = $firebaseObject(rek)
 return obj.$loaded();
 });
});
}
}
```

Comment: you forget to mention your problem

Comment: @Anik Islam Abhi Is this code correct? I am getting error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: it should be Yetki.prototype.Alis than Yetki.Alis

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
Yetki.Alis = function()  {    

$firebaseAuth(ref).$onAuth(function(uyeDurum) {

var uyexDurum = uyeDurum;

return $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(uyexDurum.uid));
```

doesn't return promise. So you need go to doc api and read about $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(uyexDurum.uid)). Or you can use $q example:

```
function($q){
   var def = $q.defer;
   $firebaseAuth(ref).$onAuth(function(uyeDurum) {
      def.resolve($firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(uyexDurum.uid)));
   }
   return def
}
```

Comment: So you return obj.$loader() which should be promise. Am i right? Now u need to etki.Alis().then(...) and it should be work.

Comment: No its not working. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: it means that obj.$loaded() doesn't return promise.

Comment: try to console log what is returned from Alis

Comment: Its return undefined. `obj.$loaded().then(function(response){console.log(response.data)});`, `undefined`

Comment: So, right now you know what's the problem. If i cau you help more feel free.

Comment: @Errorpor Okay i fix that. Right now problem is `return obj.$loaded().then(function(data){return data})` returns correct object in factory. But When I use Alis in `run` block like this `Yetki.Alis().then(function (data) {if (data.role === 'fansub') ` Getting undefined.

Comment: debbug it with console.log ;) Good luck